# Is a reduction to a non-scalar value ever useful/used?

Tags: python, functional-programming, reduce

Normally, I will see a reduction that reduces some sequence into a value. Just using the most basic example, let's do a `sum` and `count` reduction:

```
# sum
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [1,2,3])
# 6

# count
reduce(lambda x,y: x+1, [3,4,5], 0)
# 3
```

Is a reduction that doesn't produce a scalar value ever used? Here's a toy example:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+[y+2,], [1,2,3], [])
[3, 4, 5]
```

If so, what might be some actual uses of doing a reduction that produces another sequence rather than a final(ish) scalar value?

Comment: As an intermediate product to be used by another reduction that produces a scalar product?

Comment: @Sebastian I see, would you want to give an example of that then (and how would that differ then from just doing another `map` ?) [Answering my question] Oh...no `map` can only use a single value in the sequence, whereas reduce has access to multiple values in essence, so that might be a difference).

Comment: Note that your toy example is really just "list comprehension done poorly" though: `result = [x+2 for x in [1,2,3]]`, no lambdas required. So it would probably be a good idea to first have a real use case for which other list operations _don't_ make sense. Or seem cludgy.

Comment: A reduction that doesn't change the type constructor (`[]` in your example) witnesses the fact that `reduce` is more general as `map`, because you can express the latter with the former. It gets more interesting if the type constructor is changed, though, from `[]` to map for instance (I dunno Python's built-in types). I'd call this quite useful.

Comment: if you have nested list `data = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]` then using `reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, data, [])` you can reduce it to flatten list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. But the same you can do with `sum(data, [])`. Maybe you don't see this type of reduction because people prefer to use normal `for`-loop or list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

In Python? Usually not, although more by convention than anything else.

In a more general sense, it *frequently* makes sense to reduce to a non-scalar, in functional languages this is often a way to build or transform collections. Especially if you need to perform logic on the accumulated aggregate as you're iterating.

Consider the following Javascript. JS may not be extremely functional, but its `for` loops are so ugly that it has become fashionable to write with a functional accent:

```javascript
xs.reduce((coll, x) => {
  const {value, id} = x;
  if (!(id in coll)) {
    coll[id] = [];
  }

  coll[id].push(x);
  return coll;
}, {});
```

This reduction takes data like this, like one might get from a REST endpoint:

```
[{"id": 5, "value": "a"}, {"id": 5, "value": "b"}, {"id": 7, "value": "a"}]
```

and makes it look like this:

```
{"5": ["a", "b"], "7": ["a"]}
```

I see a question that boils down to this at least once a day in the Javascript tag.

In Python given the limitations of lambdas you would need to create a bespoke reducing function to achieve the same effect, but it really doesn't change much:

```python
def reducer(coll, x):
    x_id = str(x["id"])
    coll[x_id].append(x["value"])
    return coll

xs = [{"id": 5, "value": "a"}...]

result = reduce(reducer, xs, defaultdict(list))
print(result) # {'5': ['a', 'b'], '7': ['a']}
```

Works the same in Python basically, although `defaultdict` makes it shorter. But in Python there is a strong convention for list comprehensions for simple cases (they're a rare combination of concise and performant) and `for` loops for more complicated ones. Unfortunately `reduce` and friends just aren't very Pythonic, and since code is in no small part about communicating with other programmers, principle of least surprise, yadda yadda.